# Android: a spinner in a list view, Where is the OnClick/OnItemClick/OnItemSelected event?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, spinner, android-listview

I have `N` "books" each with some number of chapters.  So I create a `ListView`. Each item in the `ListView` has two parts: `TextView` for the name, and a `Spinner` to list the chapters.

I have created a custom adapter for the `ListView` - `BookAdapt`, and a custom adapter for the `Spinner` - `ChapAdapt`.  I have it displaying, and working, but I cannot find out how to add a click/selected event.

Here is the List resource

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load Chapter" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="Load"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <Button
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chapview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here is the each book display

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewbook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/chapspinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/chapter_prompt" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Here are the key parts from the `BookAdapt`

```
class BookAdapt extends ArrayAdapter {
       BookAdapt( Context context, int txtres, BookHolder[] bks) {

     super( context, txtres );
       mContext = context;
       books = bks;
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      }

      public View getView( int pos, View convert, ViewGroup parent) {
       BookHolder book = books[ pos];
       String bkname = book.getName();
       if (convert == null) {
        convert = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bookview, null);
        book.text = (TextView) convert.findViewById(R.id.viewbook);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner)convert.findViewById( R.id.chapspinner);
        ChapAdapt ch = new ChapAdapt( book, mContext);
              sp.setAdapter( ch);
        //convert.setClickable(true);
        convert.setTag( book);
       } else {
        book = (BookHolder)convert.getTag();
       }
       book.text.setText( bkname );
       return convert;  
      }
```

The `ChapAdapt` just assign a `TexTView`.

Answer (score 0):

The Spinner itself implements the `OnClicklistener`, so that it can pop up and allow you to select the respective item. After selection `Spinner.onClick()` should be called by the system, so I think this is the place you are looking for.

What you are trying to do sounds a lot like a use case for an `ExpandableListView` to me - perhaps that may be interesting too.